# Modelling database structures for volatile hierarchy of objects

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling, database-performance

**[Note: start]**

Hopefully, there are some of you, professionals, that have already had to cope with this kind of situation.
The particular case concerning post office is fictional and was made just to present the problem.
This question is not about improving performance by adding indexes.

**[Note: end]**

Recently I've been wondering how to **efficiently(!)** create a database structure to handle volatile hierarchy levels.
Let's get into the example for a better understanding of the matter.

Suppose we have a post office that stores physical mails in different ways depending on really any factor (that doesn't matter here).
We are to map this situation onto a database model.

Ok, so we have those mails. Mails can be physically stored in cases, boxes, drawers, safe deposits and many many more (because we don't want to strict our storage types and structure, but instead allow it to be flexible to meet our future changes). This means that for now we have such types, and for instance one mail can be inside a box that is stored in a safe deposit, but there can be really any combination.

For simplicity of this case let's assume that a single mail is the lowest granularity we can get. We have to remember, though, that we may also have for example empty box (that has no objects both beneath and above it) and we also want to store this in DB.

This model has to:

- be efficient - it can't (or should it?) all be stored in a single table, since we process many mails per day
- be adjustable - we may need to change our way of storing some already existing objects, so we need those grouped hierarchies to change for some objects
- be flexible - we are definitely going to need to add new objects in the future and so the hierarchy may change for upcoming and already existing particular objects

**[My idea]** So far I've come up with this idea:

Let's store all objects in one self-referencing "hierarchy" table and mark each object to be of some type, so that recursively we can see the path of where the email is located, or show every object with hierarchy that on the top depends on safe deposit.
This method would require :

a) every record to be detailed in this table, which makes it contain many null values, since mails are not described by the same attributes as a drawer,

b) or each object type might have its own table describing it, with a foreign key in "hierarchy table"

**[Warning]** This table can grow so big that lookup may cause serious performance issues. This would also require us to add new structure (physical table) for every new object in our "hierarchy of storage units", which I think is fine.

**[Question]** Could you please let me know if my idea (consider B to be my chosen requirement) is the best I can get? What can I improve?

**[SAMPLE DATA]**

Emails Table:

```
id
---
1
2
```

Cases Table:

```
id
---
1
2
```

Boxes Table:

```
id
---
1
```

Hierarchy-relation Table:

```
seq | id_obj | obj_type | id_parent_obj | parent_obj_type |
#1  |  1     | Email    |  1            | Case            | -- email 1 in case 1
#2  |  1     | Case     |  1            | Box             | -- case 1 in box 1
#3  |  1     | Box      |  [null]       | [null]          | -- box 1 no parent
#4  |  2     | Email    |  [null]       | [null]          | -- email 2 no parent
#5  |  3     | Email    |  1            | Box             | -- email 3 in box 1
#6  |  1     | Box      |  [null]       | [null]          | -- box 1 no parent
```

Just by the look on this sample data I see that we have some redundant information for example about the box in Hierarchy-relation table in `seq #3 and #6`. I think there is some different approach to this, also the refferential should be kept on `seq`, I think.
We can see though, that `case 2` is empty.

Comment: So first idea: Don't do that! Second idea: Why are you trying to reinvent XML? Third idea: Please poste some data you might want to store there and explain, why the common approaches do not fit to your needs...

Comment: @Shnugo thank you for your comment. I'm in need of making such model using DBMS, best if it could be a relational one. What actually are the common approaches?

Comment: Well, this question is hard on the "to be closed because it's to broad", but I'll try to give an answer...

Comment: @Shnugo I'm attaching sample data.

Comment: Your  update makes things clearer. Yes, exactly what you found yourself (redundant information) is to be `normalized`. The common way are isolated entities with `Foreign Keys` and/or `mapping tables`

Answer (score 1):

You should define your storage types in one "normal" table.

Add all information to this table, which is bound to the storage itself. But nothing about the things stored in there.

If storages can be "nested" (e.g. boxes within bigger boxes within a ...) you could either add a "self-join" (you did not state your RDBMS, SQL Server offers `HIERARCHYID` for this) to specify the location as a reference to the `parent storage`, or you could define a Locator table where you store the IDs of a storage and the IDs of its container (1:n -> One storage can be located in exactly one container).

Than you need a table with your items to store. If you have only one kind of item ("mails") you need a table to define a "mail" with all its attributes.

You can either put the location (the place it's stored) as a foreign key to the storages right into the "mail" table (so each mail knows its location), or - again - you can define a mapping with the mail's ID and the storage ID.

The second approach is needed, when you want to add more information to the process "I store a mail" (e.g. who, when, price, ...) and you could historize this. If you change a location you just set a "ValidUntilDatetime" and add a new line with the new location. So you can follow the process of putting things around... If this was just an FK-column within your mails table, this would not be possible.

If there are more items to store, you could think about a Master-table and as many different item tables as you have different things to store. They share an ID. General information (also the location) are part of the master table, specific data part of the sub tables.

Well, I hope this gets you on the right path...

EDIT: Answer your question from your comments:
ad "Why need of locator table":

Just image a table

```
CREATE TABLE storage(id INT, Name VARCHAR(100), ...)
```

And sample data like

```
id    Name, ...
1     Box1  ...
2     Box2  ...
3     Case1 ...
[...]
```

And a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Mail( id INT, Creation DATETIME, From VARCHAR(100), To VARCHAR(100),LocationID INT FOREING KEY REFERENCES Storage(id),...)
```

And sample data like:

```
id    Creation          From          To            LocationID    ...
1     2015-10-28 12:00  adr@mail.com  xyz@mail.com      2         ...
2     2015-10-28 12:05  adr@mail.com  xyz@mail.com      2         ...
3     2015-10-28 12:10  adr@mail.com  xyz@mail.com      3         ...
```

This would make clear, that mails 1 and 2 are physically stored in Box2 and mail 3 is stored in Case1. But you have no information about: Who put it there? When was it put there? How long will it stay there? Who will come to pick it?...

If you have a locator table like

```
CREATE TABLE Location(id INT, mailID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Mail(id),storageID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Storage(id), When, ...)
```

You can store the "put-process". If an item is transfered from Box2 to Box1 you would change the locationID in the first example. But you would not keep the information that this item was in Box2 before, who transfered it, when this happend and so on...

ad "different ways to store": If a mail is stored "no where", you might allow the storageID to remain NULL, or you define a storage item called "Nowhere" and use this ID.

It is enough to store the ID of the direct container. The container itself must know where itself is located. For this read the first part of my answer.

Comment: Could you also attach an example, to clarify the need of Locator table (I don't see use of this information in mapping tables for each "mail") and how the master-table would work with other tables? Let's assume that we have mails, cases and boxes with combinations: mail in case in box, mail in box, mail alone, mail in case?

Comment: The trick is that each mail can be stored differently. One can be inside a case, one can be inside a box, another one can be kept loose etc. What is   the structure that keeps information about this?

Comment: @ConsiderMe, I'm curious... Could I shine some light into this? Are there still open questions?

Comment: @ConsiderMe, Just saw that your are around at the moment... Look, I invested quite some time into this and would really like to see, whether I could help you or not. So please give a little feedback, Thx!

Comment: @Shungo, sorry for the delay. Please correct me if I'm wrong, considering >1 objects. Create table for each object, storing it's own object-dependent data. Create a table which holds sequence, each objects id and it's parent - location (bulding a tree-structure) with unique constraint of objects id (one object appears only once). The only dependency they share is that "master" table holds IDs of each object of every type. Am I correct?

Comment: @ConsiderMe, If I understand you correctly, that's close, but not yet perfect ;-)  Assuming you take the (better) mapping table solution: The object has its own data, nothing more. Each single loaction (=storage entity) has its own data **and** a self referenced FK to a parent storage (if it is within a container, if not, this is NULL or some virtual top node). The mapping table knows the object's ID, the storage's ID, and data related to the put-process (when, who, how long, OutDate...). An index makes sure, that an object can only have one current location (with OutDate IS NULL). Clear?

Comment: @ConsiderMe, while thinking about this, I find one flaw: I think you need four tables: 1) object 2) storage 3) put_object_into_storage 4) put_storage_into_storage. 3 and 4 are roughly the same. This would allow you  to take a filled box from one place to another simply be giving the box a new locattion. In this case you would not store the box's location as self ref FK

Comment: @Shungo, the put-process is going to be kept in a different table, and for now should not be considered. With that in mind, I only need objects tables and storage table - as you said with each object id (lets say all object tables share one sequence), id as sequence, and parent id as self referenced FK. This way I can hold current position of objects in storage table. Correct?

Comment: @ConsiderMe, You may go this way, but be aware the the mapping table between object and its location (as well as the mapping table between a location and its direct containment) **IS** the put-process. I would not store this information twice...

Comment: could you please attach an example of those 2 situations in your answer? If you got time, of course. That would clarify everything, I guess.

Comment: @ConsiderMe, just postet another answer. Please have a look on it!

Answer (score 1):

Here a complete model (air code, untested...)

```
CREATE TABLE StorageType(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                        ,StorageTypeName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO StorageType VALUES('Box'),('Case'),('OtherStorage');

CREATE TABLE Storage(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                    ,StorageTypeID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Storage_StorageTypeID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES StorageType(ID)
                    ,StorageName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
                    /*more columns to describe a storage*/
                    );
INSERT INTO Storage VALUES(1,'Box1'),(1,'Box2'),(3,'SomeStorage1');                  


CREATE TABLE ObjectType(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                       ,ObjectTypeName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO ObjectType VALUES('Mail'),('OtherItem');

CREATE TABLE MyObject(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                     ,MyObjectTypeID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_MyObject_MyObjectTypeID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ObjectType(ID)
                     ,MyObjectName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
                     /*more columns to describe an object*/
                     );
INSERT INTO MyObject VALUES(1,'Mail1'),(1,'Mail2'),(2,'SomeObject1');

CREATE TABLE StorageLocation(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                            ,CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL
                            ,OutDate DATETIME NULL
                            ,StorageID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_StorageLocation_StorageID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Storage(ID) 
                            ,ContainerID INT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_StorageLocation_ContainerID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Storage(ID) 
                            /*more columns to describe the "put storage" process: who, when, how long, ... */
                            );

INSERT INTO StorageLocation VALUES(GETDATE(),NULL,2,1); --puts the Box2 into Box1, current, because OutDate IS NULL
                            /*put all storages in their places*/

CREATE TABLE ObjectLocation (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                            ,CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL
                            ,OutDate DATETIME NULL
                            ,MyObjectID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_ObjectLocation_MyObjectID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MyObject(ID) 
                            ,ContainerID INT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_ObjectLocation_ContainerID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Storage(ID) 
                            /*more columns to describe the "put object" process: who, when, how long, ... */
                            );

INSERT INTO ObjectLocation VALUES(GETDATE(),NULL,1,2); --puts the Mail1 into Box2 (which is in Box1), current, because OutDate IS NULL
                            /*put all objects in their places*/
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, though, we seem to misunderstand each other. For every object type I'm creating a new table. I also want to have a table which stores object ids of every types (a container for all objects) and a parent-child relation. That's all. I don't feel your distinction between storage and object as a fit to my case. An object is a storage.

Comment: @ConsiderMe,  I'd rather see this like a file system. It is quite intelligent to separaten driectories from files. A file can be of any kind, can be described in any way, can be whatever it is, but a directory is a directory. As you need fast access you should try to keep things slim where the may be slim...

Comment: @ConsiderMe, and one more point: If you store different types of objects, you just need sub tables for the type sepcific data. There is the ObjectType already. General data is part of the MyObject table. specific data can be 1:1 related in a subtable with the same ID. In your code you'd modell this as object inheritance...

Comment: @ConsiderMe. one more point: You will store many objects. Yo your tables will grow big, maybe huge. But the data where the storages are located will stay rather small. Just image a recursive path of a deeply nested storage within one single table with millions of rows... I see that you try to put "everything into one" to keep it flexible... It's on you of course... But flexible equals slow... I wouldn't...

Comment: you may have a point with the ObjectType, though, I fear that table is going to grow too big. This approach also stricts every MyObject to a set of columns which must describe all objects. What if they differ? As to the first comment, the thing is, at start I may have a file, since I store information as a file, but physically, this file also contains files which are not evidenced in the system, until a certain process needs to appear, so that once a file now becomes a directory for files and new files are created under it. I may have given not enough information for my case. Sorry for that

Comment: @ConsiderMe you may "bind" objects" directly to a container (or the other way round if you need containers which **are** objects. But still I would not  see the container and the content as the same. Storing "any kind of object" needs some flexible structures. Especially if you want to introduce new object types later... This will get a hell...7

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't seem to understand you. Wish I could see what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: @ConsiderMe, well, I invested a lot of time here and there is probably no sense do create another example. If yo want you could create an answer yourself and show the model you are thinking about. I could than play the "advocatus diaboli" and tell you, were your ideas might be weak... If you don't mind, it would be very nice of you to vote my answers up (and maybe even accept one) as I spent quite a lot of time here and it would make me happy :-)